# I tried to delete admin user and then I can't login to the cyberpanel

Tags: python-3.x, django, litespeed, cyber-panel

I tried to remove the default admin user on cyberpanel as follows:

1. Create a new user with the highest authority admin
2. Login cyberpnael with new user and go to user section to delete admin user. I got an error message, I don't remember what it is. I cannot delete it.
3. Then I click on edit and try to change Owner to new user.

And as a result I get the error message: 500 Server Error.

I went into SSH and edited /usr/local/CyberCP/CyberCP/settings.py to turn on debug.
I received the following error message:

```html
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://myip:port/

Django Version: 3.1.3
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'baseTemplate',
 'loginSystem',
 'packages',
 'websiteFunctions',
 'tuning',
 'serverStatus',
 'dns',
 'ftp',
 'userManagment',
 'databases',
 'mailServer',
 'serverLogs',
 'firewall',
 'backup',
 'managePHP',
 'manageSSL',
 'api',
 'filemanager',
 'manageServices',
 'configservercsf',
 'pluginHolder',
 'emailPremium',
 'emailMarketing',
 'cloudAPI',
 'highAvailability',
 's3Backups',
 'dockerManager',
 'containerization',
 'CLManager',
 'IncBackups',
 'WebTerminal']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'CyberCP.secMiddleware.secMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/CyberCP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/CyberCP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/CyberCP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/CyberCP/loginSystem/views.py", line 150, in loadLoginPage
    currentACL = ACLManager.loadedACL(userID)
  File "/usr/local/CyberCP/plogical/acl.py", line 102, in loadedACL
    admin = Administrator.objects.get(pk=val)
  File "/usr/local/CyberCP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/CyberCP/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: Administrator matching query does not exist.
```

Can someone guide me what to do to fix this problem?
I would be extremely grateful for any feedback.

PS: I use google traslate so it can be a bit confusing. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are aware that you can create a superuser for your project. The superuser has all the rights that an admin has. If you don't know about creating a superuser, here it goes:

1. In your virtual environment, you need to browse to the project
   directory and run `python manage.py createsuperuser`.  It will then
   ask you for the username that you want to assign to that user. If
   you don't give a name and hit enter, it will name the user as
   default username on your machine.
2. Then it will ask for email address. It can be skipped by hitting
   enter without any input.
3. Finally it asks to make a password for the user and even if your
   password doesn't matches the pre-defined criteria, you can press Y/y
   and continue.

I hope this helps. If not, let me know more about your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Shashank Tiwari. My problem was solved as I said above, through running update.
I'll save the way to create superuser as you instructed and use it for the next time.
Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, can I create a new superuser and disable the default admin user? @Shashank Tiwari   <br/> I want to do this to keep the web server secure. Because, lately I see a lot of access to path
`/wp-admin/` from Cloudflare reports.

Comment: Yes @FanCanvas you can do it. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue by following the steps, here's the error you saw when deleting the admin user.
[image]

To fix this, try the following commands from the console and replace `securepassword` with your own password.

1.Create the admin user from the command line

```
cyberpanel createUser --firstName Cyber --lastName Panel --email email@cyberpanel.net --userName admin --password securepassword --websitesLimit 0 --selectedACL admin --securityLevel HIGH
```

2.Reset the admin user password again

```
/usr/local/CyberPanel/bin/python /usr/local/CyberCP/plogical/adminPass.py --password securepassword
```

3.Restart the service

```
systemctl restart lscpd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Eric. Luckily for me when I tried to solve the problem, I tried running the update command line for cyberpanel.

sh <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usmannasir/cyberpanel/stable/preUpgrade.sh || wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usmannasir/cyberpanel/stable/preUpgrade.sh)

And the miracle happened, I was able to access the cyberpanel, although it also came with some small changes in the server configuration and I had to edit it but it only took a few minutes for this.
I'll save your solution for future reference.
Thanks again

Comment: Additional: here is the command line I used to update cyberpanel
`sh <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usmannasir/cyberpanel/stable/preUpgrade.sh || wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usmannasir/cyberpanel/stable/preUpgrade.sh)` This link: [https://cyberpanel.net/docs/upgrading-cyberpanel/]